# How can I make a scatter plot of the specific columns, with a distinct marker color base on a another columns?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to use matplotlib to draw scatter plot.

I have a table like below.

[image]

How can I make a scatter plot of the first two columns, with a distinct marker color base on the fifth columns?

Comment: what is code you have already written for these ?

Comment: You can divide your problem into two parts (1) select a column from a numpy array (2) plot a scatter plot. There are numerous questions about both already, so this can be closed as duplicate. Next time asking, please make sure to state the actual problem, not only the task and show what you have tried to solve the problem. See [ask].